# Inuition for Aggregators in Adjusted Mutual Information for Clustering

Tags: python, clustering, scikit-learn, information-theory, mutual-information

A [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/372479/83252) comparing Adjusted Rand Index (ARI) and Adjusted Mutual Information (AMI) cites the rule of thumb that we should

- use ARI when the ground truth clustering has large equal sized clusters
- use AMI when the ground truth clustering is unbalanced and there exist small clusters

from a [peer-reviewed publication](https://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume17/15-627/15-627).
At [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjusted_mutual_information#Adjustment_for_chance) I see that the denominator in the formula of AMI requires an aggregator function:

$$AMI(U,V)={\frac  {MI(U,V)-E\{MI(U,V)\}}{\max {\{H(U),H(V)\}}-E\{MI(U,V)\}}}$$

At Wikipedia this is the `max` function, but other aggregators are thinkable.
For example [Scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.normalized_mutual_info_score.html) offers additional `min`, `arithmetic` and `geometric`.

The Wikipedia article states about Mututal Information (MI) that

> MI is a non-negative quantity upper bounded by the entropies H(U) and H(V).

but this is still not helping me to get a good intuition what this mean regarding the choice of the aggregator function.

So my questions are:

1. What is good intuition for each aggregator function?
2. What rule of thumb should/can I employ when choosing the aggregator function?

Comment: There are more analysis about that here: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/1756006.1953024 I noticed that empirically $\max{\{H(U),H(V)\}}$ and $H(U,V)$ worked well. By well I mean did not show exceptionally weird behaviour. E.g. once I found that $\min$ showed some weird behaviour when $U$ had many clusters and $V$ just 2. But I have no evidence for this nor I recall the exact case, so this comment is useless. The only theoretical evidence to use either `max`, `arithmetic` or $H(U,V)$ is in Table 3 of the above publication: the distance measure using those upper bounds are also *true metrics*.

Comment: @Simone: I have done quite a few experiments where I checked for `min`, `max`, `arithmetic` and `geometric` while scaling the number of clusters (e.g. changing the bandwidth in density based methods). Both `min` and `geometric` displayed "weird behavior" in different situations - especially `min`. So I second your opinion there. My question for asking arose because of my observations and also because I wanted to get a better feeling for the situation in general. I will check out the publication.

Comment: @Simone: Have you got experience with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowlkes%E2%80%93Mallows_index. I have been using it in my tests, but was not able to get a rule of thumb compared to ARI and AMI. Do you know a rule of thumb?

Comment: Sorry no experience with this. It is for clusterings with 2 clusters though.

Comment: @Simone: Thanks for answering anyway! Flowlkes-Mallows can also be used for situations with more than 2 clusters if that is what you meant.